# How to run two multiprocessing programs in one batch using SLURM?

Tags: hpc, slurm

I have SLURM cluster with several nodes with 16 vcpus per node. I've tried to run the following code:

```
#SBATCH --nodes 2
#SBATCH --ntasks 2
#SBATCH -c 16

srun --exclusive --nodes=1 program1 &
srun --exclusive --nodes=1 program2 &
wait
```

`program1` and `program2` needs 16cpus each and I expected that 2 nodes with 32 cores would be allocated and `program1` would be ran on the first node and `program2` on the second one, but I got the following error message:

```
srun: error: Unable to create step for job 364966: Requested node configuration is not available
```

If I use only `--nodes` and `--ntasks` keys, sbatch allocates 2 nodes with 2 cpus and if I use `--nodes` and `-c` options, I get message that `--ntasks` should be defined.

If I set `--ntasks=1`, SLURM set nnodes to 1.

How can I run this two programs in one batch, each on one node and 16 vcpus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems working:

```
#SBATCH --nodes 2
#SBATCH --exclusive

srun --exclusive --nodes=1 -c 16 --ntasks 1 prog1 &
srun --exclusive --nodes=1 -c 16 --ntasks 1 prog2 &
wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
#SBATCH --nodes 2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node 16

srun --exclusive -n 16 program1 &
srun --exclusive -n 16 program2 &
wait
```